# How to make Java code pause and resume after event without polling

Tags: java, file, queue, wait, polling

I am working in 2 applications.
In the first one I need to detect if a file or folder has been modified. I would like to do this without continuously polling the file to save system resources. I have been taking a look at the Google Drive program and it doesn't consume any resources while there is no modifications on the synced folder, is this possible in java?

Lastly I am trying to implement an input stream that reads characters from a Queue until it finds a new line character '\n'. I would like for it to pause if the Queue is empty until it is populated again, how could this be done without continuously checking if the Queue is empty? Please remember that an InputStream is supposed to pause the program's execution while it gets the data.

Comment: 1- Check out [Watching a directory for changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html); 2- Check out [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) - don't know if that one will help or not

Comment: +1! solution 1 is the perfect way! but be careful: while in windows you can watch a directory and its subdirectories and files within one watcher, in linux you have to watch all files seperately!

Comment: that is precisely what i was looking for, thanks so much.